# What is the correct notation for further specification of a noun/object?

Tags: punctuation, commas

What's the correct way to write the following:

> The customer, Mr. Daniels, was not able to ensure transport of the goods.

I am bothered by the fact that it is in some contexts hard to determine if there are two people, the customer & Mr. Daniels or just one. I really want to write

“The customer (Mr. Daniels), ...” or

“The customer = Mr. Daniels, ...”
 but both are clearly inappropriate in most cases.

Comment: There's no ambiguity in your first example -- it's clear that the customer and Mr Daniels are the same person. "Mr Daniels" is called a supplementary appositive noun phrase.

Comment: You could improve your example by adding another name: *The customer, Mr. Daniels, and Ms. Jones were not able...*

Comment: The construction is called an "appositive". Two noun phrases together, usually with a comma, are said to be "in apposition" if they both refer to the same individual; the second one is essentially extra information and doesn't figure into the sentence.

Comment: The crucial thing about supplementary appositives like the one in your example is that the appositive NP is not a modifier of the first NP (the 'anchor'). Integrated appositives, on the other hand, are modifiers, as in "Our friend the mayor came to dinner", where "the mayor" modifies "friend".

Comment: @BillJ - The ambiguity is in whether "Mr Daniels" is the customer or the person being addressed in the quote.

Comment: You could leave out the commas.

Comment: You could use dashes instead of commas to set off the appositive. In the UK, en-dashes would be normal.

Comment: @HotLicks -- That ambiguity would only occur, I would think, in a quote, in which case the person being spoken to would, generally, know if they were Mr. Daniels or not.  But, I could see that someone reading such might get confused if there were lots of characters and it was difficult to keep track of who they all are.

Comment: There's no implication that "Mr Daniels" is a vocative. This is a simple appositive construction.

Comment: Hm. So how about a version were the plurality doesn't give you any hints. Maybe something like "The customers, woodworkers and nurses are all putting in extra effort." So are the (wookworkers and nurses) = customers or are there three groups?